# HasDefaultValue/HasDefaultValueSql not working with SQL Server - Fluent API with EF core 5

Tags: sql-server, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-5.0

POCO model:

```
    public partial class Enterprise
    {
        public Enterprise()
        {
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

Fluent API usage:

```
    public partial class EnterpriseContext : DbContext
    {
        public EnterpriseContext ()
        {
        }

        public EnterpriseContext (DbContextOptions<EnterpriseContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Enterprise> Enterprise { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Enterprise>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.CreatedAt).HasColumnType("datetime").HasDefaultValueSql(" 
                                                                                (getdate())");

                entity.Property(e => e.Domain).HasColumnName("Domain")
                .HasMaxLength(255).HasDefaultValue("test");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(255);

                entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedAt)
                .HasColumnName("UpdatedAt")
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
            });
           }
   }
```

Code saving a DB entity into DB:

```
Enterprise enterprise = new Enterprise();
enterprise.Name = "random";
_context.Enterprise.Add(enterprise);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

This generates the following query as per EF core logs:

```
[2021-04-20T09:25:14.145Z] Executed DbCommand (69ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 255)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
[2021-04-20T09:25:14.147Z] SET NOCOUNT ON;
[2021-04-20T09:25:14.148Z] INSERT INTO [Enterprise] ([Name])
[2021-04-20T09:25:14.149Z] VALUES (@p0);
```

The columns for which default value has been configured in Fluent API namely- CreatedAt, Domain are being set as NULL in DB.
So, the question is why the Fluent API configuration is **not** working here.
I have tried a lot of P&C in Fluenet API configuration but to no avail.
Any help would be much appreciated here. Thanks!

Comment: Have you read through [Date/time value generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=fluent-api#datetime-value-generation) yet?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes i did and that is what i am using here. Even string property(Domain) is not getting set with default value "test" .

Answer (score 0):

It's because you defined the properties on the model as `DateTime?` which means they are nullable fields and therefore EF Core will make them nullable columns in SQL Server as well. You maybe able to workaround this by adding `.IsRequired(true)` before `.HasDefaultValue()` or by turning them into regular non-nullable `DateTime` properties.

Comment: why is Domain not being set with default value as "test" as defined in Fluent API configuration? It is a non-null field